# "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: - Using Absolute Path

Tags: python, opencsv, errno

I'm going nuts as I've done a lot of searching.  Here is the Python code:

```
import os
def checknum(datafile):
    lrow = []
    mess="All OK."
    with open(datafile, "rb") as f:
```

.
.
.

```
DATADIR = "c:\data"

DATAFILE = "Wind Turbine Power Data_Test_GEInternal.csv"
datafile=os.path.join(DATADIR,DATAFILE)

mess=checknum(datafile)
```

I'm using the whole path.  What am I missing?

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: DATADIR="C:\data" fails too?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give the **full text** of any errors you are getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an extra backslash in the data dir name:

```
DATADIR = "c:\\data"
```

Backslashes need to be escaped in string constants. Alternatively, you can use a `/` instead, with no problems in python:

```
DATADIR = "c:/data"
```

or

```
DATADIR = r"c:\data"
```

Comment: you can also use a raw string literal: `r"c:\data"`

Comment: You're right, I didn't provide the full message.  Here it is:  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\data\\Wind Turbine Power Data_Test_GEInternal.csv'    Note the \\.  None of the proposed solutions worked.  I probably also need to note that this is a Windows 64 Bit system - Windows 7.  I had not researched the os package.  So, I'll do that.  Are you saying that os will treat text as RE?  I'm very new to Python.  The course I just took just implemented code in a similar problem like I did, so I'm a little buffaloed.

Comment: Can you check your c:\data directory for the exact name of your csv? I suspect there is a a typo.

Comment: Yes, upper case "C" also does not work.  I intentionally did a C/P of the file name so that I wouldn't make a typo.  I checked anyway (a few times, since this just shouldn't be happening).  Sorry, it's spelled right.

Comment: Now, here's the other wrinkle.  Being Windows, it has a bizarre directory system.  The path can also be D:\Users\MyUID\data.  Is that a cause for concern?  Actually, when I use that path, Python mangles my UID.  I don't want to explore a new problem.

Comment: Try then DATADIR="D:\\Users\\MyUID\\data"

Comment: Well, rats!  I just found the typo!  A missing space.  Thanks for your help.  On to the next adventure.